# Set defaults for IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

Silverlight has IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

I'm basically looking for an equivalent to AppSettings in ASP.NET where I can set defaults.
How do I set defaults in an XAML file for ApplicationSettings?

The [documentation doesnt explain how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(VS.95).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can [do like these guys did](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/15029.aspx) and build a wrapper class that houses the defaults.

And here's a case where somebody used initialization parameters for that purpose:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2007/06/20/getting-your-initparams-from-managed-code.aspx

Comment: or should i be using a resource file?